# PHP: Function not running when called, returning 1

Tags: php

So I'm making a php function to take sort some user data by last name and first name. I split the data perfectly but when I try to use my sort function, instead of returning an array, it just returns 1. I even put print statements in the function to see if its executed and they never get called so I'm hella confused. Thanks for helping.

```
    <?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$data = "email:billy@poop.co;first:zilly;last:bobjoe;time:2005-03-23,email:bidlly@poop.co;first:brilly;last:dobjoe;time:2005-03-23,email:billy@poop.co;first:billy;last:bobjoeee;time:2005-03-23,email:billy@poop.co;first:bilssly;last:killer;time:2005-03-23,email:billy@poop.co;first:dilly;last:bobjoe;time:2005-03-23,email:billy@poop.co;first:billyddd;last:aero;time:2005-03-23";
$data_split = explode(",", $data);
//email:billy@poop.co;first:zilly;last:bobjoe
// EMAIL FIRST LAST
// array_push(arr, item)
$data_sorted = [];
foreach ($data_split as $user){
    $user_info = explode(";", $user);
    $this_user_data = [];
    foreach ($user_info as $user_piece) {
        $split_item = explode(":", $user_piece);
        $this_user_data[$split_item[0]] = $split_item[1];
    }
    array_push($data_sorted, $this_user_data);
}
// sort by last name then first name
if (!function_exists("sort")){
function sort($arr_unsorted) {
    print_r("hello");
    if (count($arr_unsorted) <= 1) {
        return $arr_unsorted;
    }
    print_r("hello?");
    $arr = $arr_unsorted;
    $swaps = 0;
    do {
        $swaps = 0;
    for ($i=0;$i<count($arr) - 1;$i+=1){
        // 0 , 1 compare... if (a,b)->-1  (b,a) -> +1 (b,b) -> 0
        $result = strcasecmp($arr[$i][last], $arr[$i + 1][last]);

        if ($result > 0){
            $temp = $arr[$i];
            $arr[$i] = $arr[$i + 1];
            $arr[$i + 1] = $temp;
            $swaps += 1;
            print_r("swap");
        }
        else if ($result == 0){
            $result_first = strcasecmp($arr[$i][first], $arr[$i + 1][first]);
            if ($result_first > 0) {
                $temp = $arr[$i];
                $arr[$i] = $arr[$i + 1];
                $arr[$i + 1] = $temp;
                $swaps += 1;
                print_r("swap");
            }
        }

    }
    } while ($swaps != 0);

    return $arr;
}
}
print_r($data_sorted);
$new_arr = sort($data_sorted);
print_r($new_arr);
```

This should return The unsorted array, then the sorted one, but it returns the unsorted array and then just a 1...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => billy@poop.co
            [first] => zilly
            [last] => bobjoe
            [time] => 2005-03-23
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => bidlly@poop.co
            [first] => brilly
            [last] => dobjoe
            [time] => 2005-03-23
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [email] => billy@poop.co
            [first] => billy
            [last] => bobjoeee
            [time] => 2005-03-23
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [email] => billy@poop.co
            [first] => bilssly
            [last] => killer
            [time] => 2005-03-23
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [email] => billy@poop.co
            [first] => dilly
            [last] => bobjoe
            [time] => 2005-03-23
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [email] => billy@poop.co
            [first] => billyddd
            [last] => aero
            [time] => 2005-03-23
        )

)
1
```

again, thanks for any help this due tomorrow

Comment: PHP also has a function named [sort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php), so your custom sort function has not been defined, you are using PHP's sort function which return a boolean value. Try changing your sort function to a different name.

Comment: yoooo you're a legend thats exactly what it was. Thank you!

Comment: also think about putting this in its own class then you could define a 'sort_last_then_first' function as well as a 'main' or 'index' function